# I am unable to use built in camera activity in android

Tags: android, video, android-activity

This is raw code of main activity    when i start the app and click on reocrd_video button it says unfortunately app has stopped.

i have added simple intent to launch default hardware camera

```
   private void video_record (View v){
    File Video_file = getFile();
       Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
       Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(Video_file);
       startActivityForResult(i,result_code);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==result_code){

            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Video saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else{

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error has occured",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private File getFile(){

        File Folder = new File("/storage/sdcard1/mycamera");
        if(!Folder.exists()){

            Folder.mkdir();
        }
        File video_file = new File(Folder,"step1.mp4");
        return video_file;
    }

}
```

Comment: which device? what app stopped? yours or the camera?

Comment: And?... have you tried to capture logs?

Comment: @yosriz mine which i am building.

Comment: @anubhavsharma We are not asking if that is your device or if you paid or stole it. Device model, and logs please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @bc004346
micromax nitro2 i am using.
dont know how to track logs it will be helpful if you guide me how to do so

Comment: tracking log (android logcat) is basic functionality when writing and debugging android apps (and it is pretty straight forward from Android Studio), please read more about that, and attach log where the crash occurs.

Comment: @yosriz Thanks will see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very helpful for you, check this link.
http://androidexample.com/Camera_Video_Capture_And_Save_On_SDCard_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=123